# Google Cloud - Organization

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I had a domain name that I used actively on Google Workspace. I had to move this domain name to another platform. I linked another domain to my existing Google Workspace account.

I was using Google Cloud free services at my previous domain. When I log in to Google Cloud after connecting my new domain, my old domain name still appears in the "Organization" section and I cannot change it. I can't add a new organization either. How can I change the existing organization or add a new organization.

I was thinking it will change on google cloud after domain name change. There are projects under the current organization. Do I need to delete these projects in order for this organization to be fully disabled? Actually, I don't really care about old projects. The most important point for me right now is to be able to add my new domain name as an organization on google cloud. Please guide me :)

Comment: There is a documentation page for migrating organizations, I think you can partially follow it without migrating the projects https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration#:~:text=Go%20to%20the%20Billing%20page%20in%20the%20Google%20Cloud%20console.&text=Click%20on%20the%20name%20of,Management%20page%2C%20click%20Change%20organization.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my old domain is still listed when I click on change payment account because the new domain is not showing up.